# How to make one micro service instance at a time run a script (using dockers)

Tags: node.js, docker, microservices

I'll keep it simple.

I have multiple instances of the same micro service (using dockers) and this micro service also responsible of syncing a cache.
Every X time it pulls data from some repository and stores it in cache.

The problem is that i need only 1 instance of this micro-service to do this job, and if it fails, i need another one to take it place.

Any suggestions how to do it simple?

Btw, is there an option to tag some micro-service docker instance and make him do some extra work?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of orchestrator are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The responsibility of restarting a failed service or scaling up/down is that of an orchestrator. For example, in my latest project, I used Docker Swarm.

Currently, Docker's [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart) are:

- **no**: Do not automatically restart the container when it exits. This is the default.
- **on-failure**[:max-retries]: Restart only if the container exits with a non-zero exit status. Optionally, limit the number of restart retries the Docker daemon attempts.
- **unless-stopped**: Always restart the container regardless of the exit status. When you specify always, the Docker daemon will try to restart the container indefinitely. The container will also always start on daemon startup, regardless of the current state of the container.
- **always**: Always restart the container regardless of the exit status, but do not start it on daemon startup if the container has been put to a stopped state before.